# Why is my WPF user control event using Caliburn Micro failing with Target not found error?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I've got a simple user control that exposes a "OptionsClicked" event. I've added this control to another view (FileView). I've used Message.Attach to attempt to bind this event to a method on the FileView's ViewModel. When the click is fired, it ends up throwing an exception that the target isn't found.

Here's the XAML:

```
<uc:DataStructure FileName="{Binding GridSelection.FullName}" 
                              cal:Message.Attach="[Event OptionsClicked] = [Action Options()]"
                              cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Source=FilesViewModel}">                    
            </uc:DataStructure>
```

Initially I didn't have cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext set, but after going through similar questions here it seemed like this was needed. However, even with this, it doesn't work (still throws the exception).

FilesViewModel is configured in my AppBootstrapper code like this:

```
container.Singleton<FilesViewModel>("FilesViewModel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your binding for `TargetWithoutContext` works correctly? If you add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the binding all the steps of binding a value to that property will be traced into debug output, maybe it ends up being a null.